# Firebase efficient structuring of data?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Let's say I have the following structure, and I want to run a query to display a list of photos/ their author photo and name. What's the best way to structure and query this?

In one hand I don't like to duplicate data (user.name, and user.photoUrl) under each photo. In the other hand I think there is no clean way to either include full user in the photo query, or fetch a list of users based on a list of ids (Basically an IN statement)?

```
users
   user1
      name: "A"
      photoUrl: "LINK"
   user2
      name: "B"
      photoUrl: "LINK"

photos
    photo1
       author: user1
       photoUrl: "Link"
       likesCount: 120
```

Answer (score 0):

Data duplication in NoSQL systems is extremely common - disk space is cheap. However, if not done properly it can over complicate matters and 'code you into a corner': updating a data set requires multiple updates to the database.

A few options for a solution are

```
1) Duplicate Data
2) Nest queries
3) Simplify
```

1) Duplicate data : This is fairly obvious and mentioned in your question, add the user info to each photo. Don't avoid this solution as it's often times the way to go.

2) Nest queries : Pretty straight forward as well:  load all photos nodes into an array, then iterate over the array and load each author. This is also common but you have to take the asynchronous nature of Firebase into account and ensure you're not working with the data until function closures complete.

3) Simplify your structure : It appears from your example that you have a one to many relationship.

Each author/user has multiple photos, so keeping is simple, store the photo data with the author.

```
user_0
   name: "A"
   photos
     photo_0
      url: "asdasd"
      likes: 123
     photo_1
      url: "fghfhf"
      likes: 42
user_1
   name: "B"
   photos
     photo_0
      url: "qqqqqq"
      likes: 12
     photo_1
      url: "wwww"
      likes: 16
```

I am all about [Denormalizing data](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html) - the flatter the better. However, it all depends on the use case so it's not a requirement and in this situation, based on the data in the question, simplifying would probably be the best solution.